# Can you explain it better why this happens?

Tags: c#, devexpress, aspxgridview

There is this article http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/K18183 about binding the ASPxGridView in Page_init for sorting , paging... to work, why does that not work on page_load?? both Page_init and Page_load are called on every PostBack so it should work in both ways , is it something to do with viewstate?

Comment: Why don't you contact DevExpress support directly?

Answer (score 0):

By default, the ASPxGridView operates through callbacks, when the ViewState is not persisted.

So, it is necessary to follow recommendations from the mentioned KB in order to apply the DX grid best practices.